# Getting the correct process id from child processes

Tags: node.js

So, I'm spawning a few processes and trying to figure out the PID of the process when it gets some data, here's my code:

```
var mod_child_process = require('child_process');
var mod_events        = require('events');

for (var i=0; i<3; ++i)
{
    var childProcess;

    childProcess = mod_child_process.spawn('HandShake.exe', ['N:192.168.200.250:3001:1', 'Q:TIME']);    

    childProcess.stdout.on('data', function(data) {         
    console.log('stdout (' + childProcess.pid + '): ' + data);
    });

}
```

It always returns a single pid

```
stdout (78748): 18/7/13 15:46:26
stdout (78748): 18/7/13 15:46:26
stdout (78748): 18/7/13 15:46:27
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're running into a scoping issue with the variable `childProcess`. Variables in JavaScript are function scoped. Because of this, the variable isn't exclusive to the loop.

Simplified example of code acting how you have it:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    var someNumber = i;

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(someNumber);
    }, 100);
}
```

outputs: `2, 2, 2`

And the fix:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    (function() {
        var someNumber = i;

        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(someNumber);
        }, 100);
    })();
}
```

You want to wrap your logic in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) so that the variable `childProcess` exists with that scope. The above code outputs the expected `0, 1, 2`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a closure problem. Pass the loop variable to a function so that scope is not affected.

```
var mod_child_process = require('child_process');
var mod_events        = require('events');

for (var i=0; i<3; ++i)
{
    var childProcess;
    childProcess = mod_child_process.spawn('cmd.exe');  
    displayid(childProcess);  
}

function displayid(childProcess){
    childProcess.stdout.on('data', function(data) {         
    console.log('stdout (' + childProcess.pid + '): ' + data);
    });
}
```

Output is

```
stdout (368): Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
stdout (20268): Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
stdout (15728): Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
```

Without it

```
stdout (10964): Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
stdout (10964): Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
stdout (10964): Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
```

Answer (score 1):

Fun fact: by just changing `var` to `let` inside the `for` initializer you avoid this problem!

Note, however, this only works if the variable is within the scope of the loop. Declare it before the loop and you get the same results as `var`.